# Bounty Notice Viewer - View the notice from Home page

Tags: script, questions, bounty

Inspired by my own meta question: [Show the bounty notice/reason on hover instead of “this question has an open bounty worth x reputation”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296956/228134),

I created a userscript which helps to view the bounty notice in the **Featured** tab.

With this, If you hover over the blue box, you can view the notice instead of the traditional message, "This question has an open bounty worth X reputation."

#### NOTICE

At present, it only supports Stack Overflow.  Will update soon.

## Example

#### Normally you see something like this

[image]

#### After installing this script, it will be

[image]

Tested with only Tampermonkey for Chrome

You can install it from [GitHub here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sagarvd01/SO/master/Src/Scripts/Bounty%20Notice%20Viewer.js)

Version: V0.1

Githu Repo: [sagarvd01/SO/blob/master/Src/Scripts/Bounty%20Notice%20Viewer.js](https://github.com/sagarvd01/SO/blob/master/Src/Scripts/Bounty%20Notice%20Viewer.js)

Author : Sagar V

License : MIT License

Feel free to Contribute for adding support to other sites

## [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Added support for all SE sites

now it will work with all SE sites including MSE.

## [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

A more improved view and performance

Comment: As you mentioned in the post, this user script is only for the featured tab, then you can change the `@match *.stackoverflow.com/*` to `@match        *.stackoverflow.com/questions/bounties/size`, it will reduce the user script is not trying to run on the all questions

Comment: That URL returning 404 @Arulkumar